# In AEM, How to transfer for approvals for all types of DAM in case of absence/ illness to the other user

Tags: workflow, aem, delegation

For all types of DAM approvals to be transferred to other, suitable business users in case of temporary absence e.g. vacation/illness.  If a person is out of the office (planned or unplanned), their approvals will need to be transferred to another user, regardless of the type of asset. How this scenario can be handled within Adobe Edxperience Manager?

Comment: An admin user should be able to finish these workflows.

Comment: are you talking about a workflow or an approval task?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot transfer approvals to another user. Only the admin can approve them and clear the cue. A possible solution to this can be assigning multiple approvers. You can add the new user in the participant step of your workflow and restart the workflow for approval, so the asset will go for approval to the new user.

Answer (score 0):

In 6.2 and up, administrators have the ability to reassign workflows to allowed users. As an admin, view the inbox and select the task that should be reassigned. "Delegate" should appear in the action bar. Here you can select a user from the dropdown. Keep in mind not all users are allowed to approve workflows, especially if you have custom permissions. The users listed in the dropdown are the only ones that have the ability to approve/complete a task.